# Javascript Node - Showing errors on nightmare module nightmare.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I can't work out why the library I have installed (nightmare is showing me errors). The errors are mainly on lines that contain :

```
=>
```

the error shows as expression expected.

when running my program I get this error from the nightmare.js:

```
      return endInstance(self, () => fn.apply(self, doneargs));
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

I get these errors too:

```
  electronLog.stdout(data);
```

expected :

In my code I can't use statements like this either:

```
.evaluate(() =>
        document.querySelector('#zero_click_wrapper .c-info__title a').href
      )
```

Error: statement expected.

Any ideas would be much appreciated. All my other node modules are fine.

Comment: My guess would be that you're using a really old version of Node.js.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I'm using v6.11.3

Comment: @JamesDonnelly just upgraded to v6.11.5 and still get the same problem